# Date time time Convertion From UTC to Local Twice

Tags: c#

I want to convert my time to universal time when I store date time in database and convert back to system time when I retrieve from the database.

Both of them I have done it success fully by creating functions **ConvertToLocalTime()**
and **ConvertToUniversalTime()**.

The code for convert to local time is given below:

```
    public void ConvertToLocalTime()
    {
        string szTimezoneinfoid = TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id.ToString();
        TimeZoneInfo tzInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(szTimezoneinfoid);

        this.m_dtCreatedDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(m_dtCreatedDate, tzInfo);
    }
```

When I call a function **Shipment.ConvertToLocalTime()** it changes the shipment created date to local time till this it works fine.

Now if I call the **Shipment.ConvertToLocalTime()** again then it consider the local time again as UTC and convert it to local time.

Is there any way to block the conversion to local time if it is already in local time?

Does there any way that we can get the time zone of the datetime?

Comment: I think you can replace your first two lines by `TimeZoneInfo txInfo = TimeZoneInfo.Local`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what's going wrong in your example, but if you simply want to get a date/time you know to be UTC from the database and convert it to local time, you can do the following:

```
var dbTime = //whatever, from database.
var utcTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dbTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var localTime = utcTime.ToLocalTime();
```

In my own project, I check `dbTime.Kind != DateTimeKind.Local` first, jut in case my data reader has decided to start performing the conversion for me.

Answer (score 2):

The result of [`TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttimefromutc.aspx) is a `DateTime` with a `Kind` of `Unspecified`, unless the time zone itself is UTC.

When you pass that result into `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc`, it will assume you *understand* it to be UTC `DateTime` - otherwise you wouldn't be calling `ConvertTimeFromUtc`...

Basically, `DateTime.Kind` is a hack to try to work around the problem that `DateTime` tries to represent too many different things. Your method starts with potentially ambiguous data, and ends up with ambiguous data... which doesn't bode well.

Either you could just make sure you always know what you're doing, and avoid calling your method with its own result, or you could consider using [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com), my alternative .NET date/time API which avoids this sort of thing by having different data types to represent different kinds of data.